# why does some software does not create new process for new file ? they run another file in same process by killing previous file e.g VLC media player

Tags: operating-system, processstartinfo

why does VLC media player does not create new process for new file like chrome do . When we click on video why does VLC kill first video and then open new one ?

Comment: It tries to open its audio device channel in exusive mode, fails?